# MongoDB nested documents searching

Tags: java, mongodb

How do I search through mongodb documents where documents have nested documents. For example I have a collection of private messages. Each private message has two nested documents - one representing the sending user and the other representing the receiving use. Both nested documents have the form -

userID: 34343,
name: Joe Bloggs

I would like to be able to search for all mail messages sent by a user (e.g. search the sender user nested document).

I am using the java driver. Do I need to create a DBObject which represents the nested document?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i understand u have document structure like this:

```
{
   "someProperty" : 1,
   "sendingUser" : {
               userID : 34343,
               name : "Joe Bloggs"
             },
   "recivingUser" : {
               userID : 34345,
               name : "Joe Bloggs"
             }
}
```

So if you need find sending user with userID = 34345 you just need do following(i just think that is so, because actually i am working with c# driver for mongo):

```
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("privateMessages")

    query = new BasicDBObject();

    query.put("sendingUser.userID", new BasicDBObject("$eq", 34345)); 

    cur = coll.find(query); // all documents with  sendingUser.userID = 34345 will be //returned by cursor
```

Also check tutorial for [java driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-GettingASingleDocumentwithAQuery)

Comment: I know this is older answer, but actually I'm getting invalid operator `$eq` :-(

Comment: try this `query.put("sendingUser.userID", 34345);`.

Comment: yes, I found that later thanks, my problem was that I used several databases and `query.put("sendingUser.userID", 34345);` returned `null` and I thought that it's not working, but the record wasn't in database, my mistake. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB Java Driver v3.2.2. You can do something like this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(Document.parse("{\"sendingUser.userID\": \"34343\"}"));
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(Document.parse("{\"sendingUser.name\": \"Joe Bloggs\"}"));
```

You can put the `$eq` inside the JSON style query string.  Like `{ <field>: { $eq: <value> } }`.