# Modify nest document's value in MongoDB for Java

Tags: java, mongodb

A very quick question, how am I going to do this below:

```
> db.blog.posts.findOne()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4b253b067525f35f94b60a31"),
"title" : "A Blog Post",
"content" : "...",
"author" : {
    "name" : "joe",
    "email" : "joe@example.com"
     }
}
```

I saw the answer in Javascript is like:

```
> db.blog.posts.update({"author.name" : "joe"}, {"$set" : {"author.name" : "joe schmoe"}})
```

But how am I going to do that in Java?

If I have a very deep level value has to be changed, am I supposed to use this way? like: "person.abc.xyz.name.address" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dot notation to access nested documents will work perfectly well in the Java Driver.  Take a look at this StackOverflow answer:

[MongoDB nested documents searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433401/mongodb-nested-documents-searching)

For the Java Driver, the basic idea is to replace the Javascript objects with instances of BasicDBObject.

Here's another good reference for updating:

[MongoDb's $set equivalent in its java Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943434/mongodbs-set-equivalent-in-its-java-driver)

Comment: hi thank your reply. One more question please, are these 2 the same? 1) db.blog.posts.find({"author.name" : "joe"})
2) db.blog.posts.find({"author : {"name" : "joe"}}

Comment: when I am using it for searching, will these 2 return the same document?

Comment: No.  The first one matches any document which contains an embedded "author" document with the field "name" equal to "joe".  The second only matches documents with an embedded "author" document which is exactly { "name" : "joe" } (with no other fields).  Think of the second as matching the "author" field exactly - the behavior is the same as if the value for "author" weren't a document.